# Androidのvideoviewでコントロール系を好きにデザインする方法

Tags: android, eclipse, videoview

Androidでvideoviewを使って動画再生を行っています。

MediaControllerを使ってコントローラーを設置することはできますが、

```
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

自分の好きにデザイン・配置する方法がわかりません。
・終了ボタン
・再生スライドバー
・再生/停止
などです。標準ボタンでもいいのですが、自分がデザイン(pngなど)を好きな位置に配置したいと思います。

調べましたがこのような方法が見つからず質問させていただいております。
関連になるようなURLでもかまいません。ご教授いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自分でデザインをカスタマイズした動画再生アプリを作るには、VideoViewではなくSurfaceViewを使用してMediaPlayerでコントロールします。SurfaceViewをextends、SurfaceHolder.CallbackとOnCompletionListener辺りをimplementsした動画再生専用のクラスを作ると便利ですよ。